# AWs SDK for Java DeleteStackResponse code examples

Tags: aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'm using the AWS SDK in my Java code and I have code that uses a CloudFormationClient to delete a stack:

```
DeleteStackRequest deleteStackRequest = DeleteStackRequest
    .builder() 
    .stackName(stack.stackId())
    .build();

DeleteStackResponse deleteStackResponse = client.deleteStack(deleteStackRequest);
```

The code is pretty straightforward and it seems to work. But I'm interested in finding documentation or examples of similar code that deletes a stack in order to validate my code.

Anyone know where I can find this? I have not yet found examples of this in the AWS SDK for Java [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html), nor in the sdk code [examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/java/example_code) on github.